# JQuery Collapsible table not working

Tags: jquery

I need some help in my JQuery code I can not seem to understand where I am going wrong.  It's a simple '**Parent**' and '**Child**' style collapsible table.  So to start with all '**children**' are hidden and if you click on a **Parent** it shows all it's **children**.  The problem with my code is when I click on a **Parent** all of it's children are shown in all the rest of the Parents too. 
Thanks

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
 $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
 $("#report tr:first-child").show();

 $('location.href').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : 'Test',
    data : '${cat.categoryId}',
 success : function(response) {
    $('ul').html(response);
    $("#report tr.odd").next("tr").toggle();
    }
     });
   });
 });
```

JSP

```
<c:if test="${!empty categoryList}">
 <table id="report">
    <tr>
        <th>Category Name</th>
    </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${categoryList}" var="cat">
        <tr onclick="location.href='${cat.categoryId}'" >
            <td>${cat.categoryName}</td>
            <td><div class="arrow"></div></td>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
            <c:forEach items="${prodList}" var="prod">
            <ul>
                <li>${prod.productName}</li>
            </ul>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
 </table>
</c:if>
```

Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value="{Id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showProductByCatId(@PathVariable("Id") Integer Id, Model model){
    List<Product> prod = purchaseOrderService.listProductsByCatId(Id);
    model.addAttribute("prodList", prod);
    model.addAttribute("categoryList",purchaseOrderService.listCategory());
    return "Test";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `#report tr.odd` in

```
$("#report tr.odd").next("tr").toggle();
```

will match all odd rows, you need to select only the clicked row with something like this

```
 $('#report tr.odd').click(function() {
      var child = $(this).next('tr');

      $.ajax({
           type : 'GET',
           url : 'Test',
           data : '${cat.categoryId}',
           success : function(response) {
                child.find('ul').html(response);
                child.toggle();
           }
      });
 });
```

**EDIT:**
You need to select the right `<ul>` as well, I've updated the code above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, now there's no toggle there all children are hidden.

Comment: I'm really sorry wazz3r this has gone back to original problem, showing clicked Parent's children in all Parents.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do. In the JSP file you already write the data to the row, why do you need an ajax call in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for your reply again, you're right I don't really need ajax call, I was hoping that It would send the data(categoryId) to controller before it can toggle/show Parent's children but after all this it may not be the JQuery problem it could be my JSP or Controller that needs changing. I thank you for your help thou.